# Details object Length Check in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a master details object contact and phone number, I can add multiple phone number according to one contact. This example is shown by knockout [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html). This is look like this

[image]

This example is working better for me. but I want to set a little condition on the delete button of phone number. Visible the delete button when phones.length > 1 . I can not set this condition on phone delete button. I have already written this code below but it did not work.

```
<td><a href='#' data-bind='visible: phones.length > 1, click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a></td>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be:

```
<td>
    <a href='#' data-bind='visible: $parent.phones().length > 1, 
                           click: $root.removePhone'>Delete</a>
</td>
```

Since you are inside the `foreach` binding, if you don't prefix with `$parent` it would be equivalent to `$data.phones` which is not what you want.